# Unreasonably large binder buffer - React Native app crashes on android device during navigation between screens

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

In my react-native android app, my application is getting crashed in some scenario :

1. Navigate to screen 1 select a record
2. Navigate to screen 2, pass data to screen being navigated
3. Navigate to screen 1 select another record
4. App crashes before navigating to screen 2

As I can see its highlighting error **Unreasonably large binder buffer** error.

Please suggest what could be reason behind that and how can it be resolved?

Below is the related code :

```
userController.userGetSellersCountByProperty(rowItem.propId).then((responseJson) => {

      if (responseJson.serverResponse.code == HttpUrlConstant.SUCCESS_CODE) {
        this.props.addAgentSellerPropRelation(responseJson.serverResponse)
        this.props.addPropertyIndex(index)
        this.goToScreen('HomeScreen')
      } else {
        alert(responseJson.serverResponse.message)
      }


    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

**Getting Response from above api call**

```
{
  "serverResponse": {
    "status": "success",
    "code": 200,
    "message": "Total Sellers Available List",
    "dataList": {
      "sellersInfo": [
        {
          "unique_id": null,
          "subscription_id": null,
          "usersRole": null,
          "firstName": null,
          "lastName": null,
          "emailId": "abcd@gmail.com",
          "authToken": null,
          "brokerageinfo": null
        }
      ],
      "totalSellers": 1
    }
  }
}
```

**Crash Log**

```
2019-07-23 11:47:58.176 958-958/? E//system/bin/tombstoned: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_06
2019-07-23 11:47:58.219 1441-12565/? E/Binder: Unreasonably large binder buffer: on android.os.BinderProxy@ffa2e1e calling 3 size 1048836 (data: 4194304, 31, 7209057)
android.util.Log$TerribleFailure: Unreasonably large binder buffer: on android.os.BinderProxy@ffa2e1e calling 3 size 1048836 (data: 4194304, 31, 7209057)
at android.util.Log.wtf(Log.java:299)
at android.util.Slog.wtfStack(Slog.java:98)
at android.os.Binder.checkParcel(Binder.java:713)
at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:1127)
at android.app.IActivityController$Stub$Proxy.appCrashed(IActivityController.java:226)
at com.android.server.am.AppErrors.handleAppCrashInActivityController(AppErrors.java:585)
at com.android.server.am.AppErrors.crashApplicationInner(AppErrors.java:460)
at com.android.server.am.AppErrors.crashApplication(AppErrors.java:422)
at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner(ActivityManagerService.java:17778)
at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener$NativeCrashReporter.run(NativeCrashListener.java:111)
2019-07-23 11:47:58.228 685-752/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only
2019-07-23 11:47:58.241 1441-1503/? E/Binder: Unreasonably large binder buffer: on android.os.BinderProxy@dea29b8 calling 2 size 1049088 (data: 21037060, 36, 6881398)
android.util.Log$TerribleFailure: Unreasonably large binder buffer: on android.os.BinderProxy@dea29b8 calling 2 size 1049088 (data: 21037060, 36, 6881398)
at android.util.Log.wtf(Log.java:299)
at android.util.Slog.wtfStack(Slog.java:98)
at android.os.Binder.checkParcel(Binder.java:713)
at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:1127)
at vivo.app.epm.IExceptionPolicyManager$Stub$Proxy.reportEventWithMap(IExceptionPolicyManager.java:280)
at vivo.app.epm.ExceptionPolicyManager.reportEvent(ExceptionPolicyManager.java:82)
at com.android.server.am.AppErrors.handleShowAppErrorUi(AppErrors.java:898)
at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$UiHandler.handleMessage(ActivityManagerService.java:2448)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:44)
at com.android.server.UiThread.run(UiThread.java:43)
2019-07-23 11:47:58.242 1441-1503/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1049088)
2019-07-23 11:47:58.242 1441-1503/? E/ExceptionPolicyManager: Dead object in reportEvent
android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 1049088 bytes
at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:1157)
at vivo.app.epm.IExceptionPolicyManager$Stub$Proxy.reportEventWithMap(IExceptionPolicyManager.java:280)
at vivo.app.epm.ExceptionPolicyManager.reportEvent(ExceptionPolicyManager.java:82)
at com.android.server.am.AppErrors.handleShowAppErrorUi(AppErrors.java:898)
at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$UiHandler.handleMessage(ActivityManagerService.java:2448)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:44)
at com.android.server.UiThread.run(UiThread.java:43)
2019-07-23 11:47:58.243 1441-5855/? E/ActivityManager: Sending non-protected broadcast com.vivo.perfdiagnosis.MSG_CENTER from system 1441:system/1000 pkg android
2019-07-23 11:47:58.269 1441-21043/? E/ActivityManager: Sending non-protected broadcast com.vivo.abe.messagecenter.exception from system 1978:com.vivo.abe/1000 pkg com.vivo.abe
2019-07-23 11:47:58.269 1441-21043/? E/ActivityManager: Sending non-protected broadcast com.vivo.abe.messagecenter.exception from system 1978:com.vivo.abe/1000 pkg com.vivo.abe
```